# MvcSiteMapProvider MVC 5 custom ViewBase?

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I have a problem after upgrading MvcSiteMapProvider MVC 4 to MVC 5.
I use a custom "pageBaseType" for my views, and it seems that MvcSiteMapProvider MVC 5 does
not allow that?
I keep getting the error:

```
The view at '~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
```

at   @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath().

However, my custom viewbase does inherit System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.
Am I missing something here?

If I remove the line @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() the page works fine, but without the sitemappath, of course.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What build of MVC 5 are you seeing this with?

Comment: I use the latest one available via nuget: version:4.6.10

Comment: No, not the MvcSiteMapProvider build, the MVC 5 build. Is this 5.1?

Comment: I just had a look at the source of the sitemapprovider, it uses the .net framework version 4, whereas i (have to) use 4.5. I think the problem might be exactly this?
@NightOwl888: I think it's 5.2...

Comment: Please look in your packages.config file for the version of "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc". The VS settings are set for .NET 4.0, but they are overridden in the build script for each MVC version when building the NuGet packages.

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
is what is in the packages.config of my web project

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but I am not getting the same error. [Here is the project](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_InheritView) you can use to try to resolve your issue.

If your project has files in it with a .aspx extension, it will cause the NuGet package to install the templates for webpages (not razor) into your project in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` directory. Check that directory to make sure that all of the files have a .cshtml extension.

If not, you can get the latest version of the .cshtml templates from [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/DisplayTemplates). Alternatively, you can copy them out of the `\packages\MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.[installed version]\content\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\` folder in your project.

Comment: In my case - it was this guy in web.config creating problem: <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" /> (it was having 5.0 instead of the correct one 5.1) I am using mvc5. –

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I figured out what was missing:
I did not have the specific assembly binding in my web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I saw this in the project you provided and added it my config... voila, it's working now.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.
I tested a simple Test view with the following simple web.config, @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() worked fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="Fairfax.Classifieds.Drive.WebMVC" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeRootNodeFromSiteMapFile" value="true" />

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

But my web.config is much more complex. I met the error with stack trace:

The view at '~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage.

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.]
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +401
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +544
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1089
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +119
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +104
   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, String templateName, ISiteMapNode startingNode, SourceMetadataDictionary sourceMetadata) +232
   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, String templateName, String startingNodeKey, SourceMetadataDictionary sourceMetadata) +70
   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper) +45
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Test_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Projects\Drive\drive\Src\Web\Views\Home\Test.cshtml:9
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I put the break point at @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath(), in Watch windows @Html.MvcSiteMap() raised an exception

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap()  'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'MvcSiteMap' and the best extension method overload 'MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.MvcSiteMap(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' has some invalid arguments
```

Could you show me which area is the most risky causing the error?